# Can Not Check Session From File PHP Call By Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I use DataTables Server Side to make Table. I call login.php to get some values from database by Ajax. This is code DataTables:

```
<?PHP session_start(); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">    
$(document).ready(function() {
    t = $('#table_stok').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "php/query/login.php"
    });
} );

</script>
```

I have call session_start() in top of Ajax. And this is file login.php to Connect to Table:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['login'])){
$db_username    = 'root';
$db_password    = '';
$db_name        = 'dbmaster2';
$db_host        = 'localhost';
}else if($_SESSION['login']==1){
$db_username    = 'root';
$db_password    = '';
$db_name        = 'dbmaster2';
$db_host        = 'localhost';
}else{
$db_username    = 'root';
$db_password    = '';
$db_name        = 'dewata';
$db_host        = 'localhost';
}

$sql_details = array(
'user' => $db_username,
'pass' => $db_password,
'db'   => $db_name,
'host' => $db_host
);
?>
```

What I get from testing, My login.php can not check session if I Run it via ajax. But when I run it via browser (localhost/dewata/php/query/login.php), it can detect session normally. Ho do I check session from php file that call by ajax? Is  Missing Code Somewhere?

Comment: call it from ajax or not doesnt matter, php will populate $_SESSION, if you have session_start(); in the top of the script, and then setting session variable to something it will be passed on

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console ?

Comment: Always check and then start session _if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}_

Comment: I got error : DataTables warning: table id=table_stok - Invalid JSON response. But When I remove function to check session exist or not, It run OK.

Comment: Thankyou LearningMode. Add if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }  and my code work :)

Answer (score 0):

I add this code :

```
if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }    
if(empty($_SESSION['login'])){
$db_username    = 'root';
$db_password    = '';
$db_name        = 'dbmaster2';
$db_host        = 'localhost';
}else if($_SESSION['login']==1){
$db_username    = 'root';
$db_password    = '';
$db_name        = 'dbmaster2';
$db_host        = 'localhost';
}else{
$db_username    = 'root';
$db_password    = '';
$db_name        = 'dewata';
$db_host        = 'localhost';
}

$sql_details = array(
'user' => $db_username,
'pass' => $db_password,
'db'   => $db_name,
'host' => $db_host
);
```

And My php function normally :)
Thanks For Help.